# getProperty of entity in Odata model in SAPUI5 not working

Tags: odata, sapui5

I have a oData model with entities : Order, OrderInformation. There is 1 : 1 an association between Order and OrderInformation.

Now in the view, based on a value in OrderInformation, I should hide / display a button.

In the controller, following logic to get the value of OrderInformation->appUrl does not work but I can read the property of entity 'Order'.

```
   Init: function(){
   // Not working
    var prop = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/OrderInformations('"+ this._orderId + "')/appUrl");
   // Working
    var prop = this.getView().getModel().getProperty("/Orders('"+ this._orderId + "')/orderType");
    }
```

In transaction /IWFND/GW_CLIENT, following query gives me correct value

```
/sap/opu/odata/sap/<<ServiceURL>>/OrderInformations('132123')/appUrl
```

I also tried with the attachRequestCompleted but still no success.

```
Init:function(){
    var oModel = this.getView().getModel();
    oModel.attachRequestCompleted(function(oEvent){
        var myval = model.getProperty("/OrderInformations('"+ this._orderId + "')/appUrl");
        });
}
```

Can someone provide any idea what can be going wrong ?

BR
Nilesh

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the oModel.read function to trigger a request to the backend, within the success handler you read the result of the response and process the received data

```
var test = oModel.read("OrderInformations('" + this._orderId + "')", {
    success: function(oData, response) {
        var appUrl = oData.result.appUrl; //response.data.appUrl also works
        // do something
    },
    error: function (oError) {
        // Error handling on failed response
    }
});
```

API reference: https://openui5beta.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel.html#read

I don't understand this line you wrote:

> In the controller, following logic to get the value of
>   OrderInformation->appUrl does not work but I can read the property of
>   entity 'Order'.

Order is another Entity with a property and the addressing for this works like described above?
Did you init your model like this:
`/sap/opu/odata/sap/<<ServiceURL>>/Order`? Is `OrderInformation` a related entity of Order? If yes extend the read with the Navigation property of the odata service which defines the relationship between the two Entities

I hope this answers you question, if anything left, let me know

Best regards

Comment: Hi,You were spot on in the analysis. I just didn't want to make another call using mode.read. Seems issue was i wa trying to read property of something that was not even loaded in memory. I did use Mode.read finally . Thanks !